# Ruby puts command creates a new line in bash

Tags: ruby

When I put the final puts command in the code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#Este comando cita sua idade e nome
puts "digite sua idade:"
idade = gets.to_i
puts "digite seu nome:"
nome = gets
puts "Olá #{nome}! você nasceu em #{2021-idade}"
```

and run it on bash, it creates a new line inside the line.
how to make it to be just **one line?**

[bash image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbfcz.png)

Comment: That's what `puts` does, add a newline (at the end of the line). You could use `print` instead.

Comment: On a second thought, `gets` does that too (in a way). Your `nome` contains a newline. `puts` does not add newlines in the middle of its arguments, only at the end.

Comment: Please edit and inline the text contained within the image you posted.

Answer (score 1):

The `print` method will continue to output on the same line.

`puts` will always add a new line.

There is a great reference here: https://flexiple.com/puts-vs-p-vs-print-ruby/

You can also always check the documentation:

`puts` - https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/IO:puts
"Note that puts always uses newlines"

`print`- https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/IO:print

If you are worried about the input having a new line, check out `gets.chomp`

https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/10/ruby-chomp-gets/

```
puts "digite sua idade:"
idade = gets.to_i
puts "digite seu nome:"
nome = gets.chomp #<- add .chomp here to remove \n from input
puts "Olá #{nome}! você nasceu em #{2021-idade}"
```

Comment: `puts` only appends a newline if there is none. It the string already ends with a newline, it doesn't add another one.

Comment: @Stefan That's not what I'm suggesting. I'm suggesting it will always include a new line in the terminal output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there's a typo in your code, and it's supposed to be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#Este comando cita sua idade e nome
puts "digite sua idade:"
idade = gets.to_i
puts "digite seu nome:"
nome = gets
puts "Olá #{nome}! você nasceu em #{2021-idade}"
```

The newline appears after the name because `gets` includes the newline character, which you then interpolate into the string you're printing. You can use `#chomp` or `#strip` to remove the newine (and potentially any unwanted whitespace around the input. You can see this by calling these in irb.

```
irb(main):003:0> gets
hello
=> "hello\n"
irb(main):004:0> gets.chomp
hello
=> "hello"
irb(main):005:0> gets.strip
  hello
=> "hello"
irb(main):006:0>
```